# Any exercises/tests/exams freely available with answers to test basic R knowledge

Tags: r

I have the responsibility of ensuring that a colleague who is just learning R knows the basics before a course where that is a requirement.  The colleague has gone through a couple of tutorials so hopefully she is ok, but I would like to give her a test to gauge it.

I was therefore wondering if anyone knew if there were any materials on the web that would be suitable? and is possible had both questions and answers.

PS Cross-posted to r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch

Comment: You may have more success with this question on stackoverflow. I've flagged it, so if the powers that be decide I'm right, it will be migrated automagically (you don't don't need to create a new question there).

Comment: please post good answers from r-help here

Comment: WIll do, but no response as yet

Answer (score 16):

There is a whole set of exercises with solutions from the book Data Analysis and Graphics Using R. (Maindonald & Braun, 2nd edn, CUP 2007) available online : http://maths.anu.edu.au/~johnm/r-book/2edn/exercises/

Next to that, a quick search using the obscure randomized pagecollector Google brought to me a set of exercises where you can pick out whatever you want. Try the magic phrase "R exercises". ;)

Some I found interesting :

- http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~das01/RCourse/Exercises.pdf (very nice)
- http://dial.liacs.nl/Courses/MicroArrayDataAnalysis/Exercises/Introduction_to_R_Exercises_Nov_2004.pdf (rather basic)
- http://www.shlrc.mq.edu.au/masters/students/raltwarg/altwargslp802.html (rather basic)

Answer (score 8):

If this is just a one time single person evaluation then a oral style exam is probably going to tell you a lot more than a set of fixed problems.  Get a data set and have her read it into R, do some basic data manipulation, a couple of plots, and a standard analysis or two.  Based on what she does well or has a challenge with you can modify the direction that you have things go and what additional questions you ask.

Comment: +1 here and to Joris, but I think this is the way to go.  Watching someone code, seeing what makes them hesitate, what they have to look up, etc would be much more useful, though much more labor-intensive on the examiner's part.

Comment: @Matt I definitely agree with @Greg